# how to get a value for another column by association in ruby on rails?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

If i have  two models like `Question` and `Answer`. `Question` has three columns like `question_id, question_type, question_text` and `Answer` has three values `answer_id, question_id, answer_text`.

I am creating form for the `Answer` model.

Example:

```
<%= f.text_field :question_id %>.
<%= f.hidden_field :question_id %>.
```

Here, I am using the `hidden field` to find the `question_type`.  I tried the `map` method, but that doesn't work. So Somebody help me to get the `question_type` value by the selection of that `question_id`.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could include question when you are pulling your answer in the controller, then you have full access to both without extra query in your view:

In controller:

```
@answer = Answer.includes(:question).where(:id => params[:answer_id])
```

In view:

```
<%= @answer.question.question_type %>
```

If this is a new answer, you can create it and pass question to it in your controller:

```
@answer = Answer.new(:question => Question.find(params[:question_id]))
```

Then in your form you can access it with:

```
<%= @answer.question.question_type %>
```

Comment: I am bit confusing. the current form is working with the answer model. In the new or edit actions renders the same form. So, when the user select the question_id, i want to get the value of question_type that matches the selected question_id.

Comment: So you are not passing question to the answer form? It's a form to answer any question?

Answer (score 1):

To piggy back on what iouri said. If the relations in your models are set up correctly you should be able to use dot notation to get the question_type as in answer.question.question_type.

You would need something like...

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :answers
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :answers
end

class Answer < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :question
end
```

So this will give you the ability to call answer.question.question_type, and also not the accepts_nested_attributes_for :answers which will help in building the association.

Ryan Bates has an excellent screencast on this here http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1

Good luck!